# Centering NSWindow's buttons (traffic lights) on OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: nswindow, osx-yosemite, inappstorewindow

In the WWDC '14 sessions, it is explained how to add subviews to a `NSWindow` title bar, which helps defining a custom height of the title bar.

However, I cannot find a way to center the window control buttons (traffic lights) vertically centered.

I tried setting their frames in NSWindow's `setFrame:display:;`, but weirdly, during resizing, the buttons stick to the top edge of the title bar.

Did anyone find a proper technique on how to center these buttons?

(I do not want to use `INAppStoreWindow` this time.)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?